Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug' /development/flutter/bin/flutter'
I recently updated Android Studio Koala and Dart plugin to latest version and started running my Flutter project. It showed this error:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> A problem occurred starting process 'command '/Users/..../development/flutter/bin/flutter''

About Android Studio:
Android Studio Koala | 2024.1.1 Patch 1
Build #AI-241.18034.62.2411.12071903, built on July 11, 2024
Runtime version: 17.0.11+0-17.0.11b1207.24-11852314 aarch64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 14.6
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 4096M
Cores: 8
Metal Rendering is ON
Registry:
  ide.balloon.shadow.size=0
  debugger.new.tool.window.layout=true
  ide.new.editor.tabs.vertical.borders=true
  ide.animate.toolwindows=true
  ide.experimental.ui=true
  ide.editor.tab.selection.animation=true
Non-Bundled Plugins:
  com.chylex.intellij.inspectionlens (1.4)
  com.zll.format (2.2)
  dev.willebrands.intellij.sloppyfocus (0.8.0)
  Dart (241.17890.8)
  PlantUML integration (7.10.1-IJ2023.2)
  com.bloc.intellij_generator_plugin (4.0.1)
  com.genymotion.idea (2.0.1)
  com.flutter_create_stateful_widget (1.5)
  andrasferenczi.dart-data-plugin (0.2.0)
  com.markskelton.one-dark-theme (5.11.0)
  com.ankit.mahadik.json.dart.class (2.16)
  com.intellij.marketplace (241.17890.39)
  com.localizely.flutter-intl (1.18.5-2023.2)
  com.herbert.george.dart.extensions (0.0.1+3)
  com.jiajun.flutter_add_image (1.7)
  com.herbert.george.flutter-snippets (2.0.0-stable-1)
  com.eggnstone.jetbrainsplugins.DartFormat (2.0.9)
  Docker (241.18034.82)
  izhangzhihao.rainbow.brackets (2024.2.4-241)
  cn.yiiguxing.plugin.translate (3.6.2)
  pl.pszklarska.pubversionchecker (1.3.5)
  com.chrisrm.idea.MaterialThemeUI (9.3.1)
  com.developerphil.adbidea (1.6.15)
  com.github.kikimanjaro.stickyscroll (0.0.2)
  com.github.copilot (1.5.14.6059-nightly)
  org.intellij.qodana (241.18034.8)
  com.mallowigi (97.0.0)
  mobi.hsz.idea.gitignore (4.5.3)
  io.flutter (80.0.2)
  com.crzsc.FlutterAssetsGenerator (2.4.2)
  de.mariushoefler.flutter_enhancement_suite (1.7.1)
  com.ruiyu.ruiyu (5.1.7)

Flutter and Dart:
Flutter 3.22.2 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 761747bfc5 (5 weeks ago) • 2024-06-05 22:15:13 +0200
Engine • revision edd8546116
Tools • Dart 3.4.3 • DevTools 2.34.3

Tried some online solutions but they didn't help

I restarted my system and it worked :)

based on this, I'm voting to close the question to Not reproducible or was caused by a typo

Ensure the Flutter path is set in the correct way in your environment variables.
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/.../development/flutter/bin"

After that restart the android studio and try cleaning and rebuilding your project:
flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter build

If still not working go to
Preferences/Languages&Frameworks/Flutter
and ensure the Flutter SDK path is correctly set.
